# Operating with class variables yields zero?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I have the following method inside a class:

```
    def initialize_overlaps(self):
    """Initialize the overlap list for each band_nk """
    for n in range(self.nbands):
        for k in range(self.nkpts - 1):
            for n_prim in range(self.nbands):
                print("Currently overlapping n: " + str(n) + ". k: " +str(k) +". n': " +
                      str(n_prim) + "\t" +str(n/self.nbands) + " percent completed.")
```

When running it, the indices of the loops change fine, but I dont know why the operation `n/self.nbands` always yields zero:

```
Currently overlapping n: 3. k: 12. n': 10       0 percent completed.
Currently overlapping n: 3. k: 12. n': 11       0 percent completed.
Currently overlapping n: 3. k: 13. n': 0        0 percent completed.
Currently overlapping n: 3. k: 13. n': 1        0 percent completed.
Currently overlapping n: 3. k: 13. n': 2        0 percent completed.
Currently overlapping n: 3. k: 13. n': 3        0 percent completed.
Currently overlapping n: 3. k: 13. n': 4        0 percent completed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `n` is always smaller than `self.nbands` and therefore the pure `/` division is `0`. You should convert one of the two values to float. The following substitution in the `print` statement would work

```
str(n/float(self.nbands))
```